# Why does css grid-column property take multiple values with a slash not a space?

Tags: css, syntax, css-grid

Why does the css grid-column property take multiple values like this:

```
grid-column: <column-start> / <column-end>;
```

Normally a property with multiple values (e.g. border-radius) would have them separated by spaces. Here they are separated by a slash. Why is this?

Comment: Actually border radius is split by slashes on occasions.

Comment: Probably because the values themselves can have spaces, like `span 2`. In this case the full property would be `grid-column: 1 / span 2;`.

Comment: I would suggest it's because it's defining two properties not one property with multiple values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is also the case for properties like [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font). As in:

```
font: 12px/18px;
```

which is a shorthand property for `font-size` and `line-height` properties.

The [`background` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) does the same:

```
background: no-repeat center / 80% url("../img/image.png");
```

In the case of `background`, to define the `background-size` you must define the `background-position`, followed by a `/`, and then the `background-size` value.

`grid-columns` is a shorthand property for `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` properties. And both these values can contain one or more spaces. Like `span 2`, or `5 somegridarea span` if using a custom identifier.

IMO, the `/` makes it more readable, and less prone to error. It also eliminates ambiguity with values that contain spaces.

For example:

```
grid-column: 1 / span 2;
```

or

```
grid-column: span 3 / 7;
```